# C# высоконагруженный клиент-сервер

Tags: c#, многопоточность, клиент-сервер

Есть сервер, у которого 20-30 активных подключений. И одно подключение к другому серверу(машина куда надо отправлять обработанные данные).
Данные с активных подключений приходят раз 1-10 секунд. Пришедшие данные обрабатываются за 2-3 секунды и отправляются на другой сервер.

Вызываю метод `BeginWrite`(начинаю запись в поток), а в `callback` методе вызываю `EndWrite`. Как я понял `EndWrite` блокируется пока данные не передадутся на другое приложение(другой сервер). И получается, что все остальные пакеты ждут пока отправятся другие пакеты. Соответственно, получается задержка и накопление очереди(если я правильно понимаю).

Как можно решить эту проблему? Или может я копаю не в том направлении?

UPD
Попробовал решить проблему организовав очередь. Т.е. Со всех активных подключений данные, которые надо отправить сперва попадают в очередь. А затем в новом thread в бесконечном цикле отправляются на другой сервер. Вывел, количество пакетов в очереди в итоге очень редко доходит до 5 пакетов, практически постоянно держится на 0. При этом ведется лог после строчки client.GetNetwork().Write(...)(специально сделал синхронную(может попробовать асинхронную запись?)), в который пишу, когда какой пакет ушел. На принимающем сервере организовал вывод информации, когда какой пакет пришел. В итоге получается, что у меня расхождение в получении пакетов, например ушло 600, а сервер принял только 520, и это расхождение возрастает. Если не переподключаться к серверу то пакеты совсем перестают доходить, хотя по логам видно что уходят. Что может быть? Куда копать? Уже совсем Себе голову сломал.

Comment: да. EndWrite блокирует поток до завершения записи.

Comment: Что из себя представляет приложение на сервере? Консольное приложение, Windows служба?

Comment: Для обеспечения масштабирования на уровне подключений к серверу,  запросы от других машин можно принимать в приложении, работающем под IIS, который предоставит Вам свой пул потоков. При правильном написании кода приложения (будь то WCF или WEB API), можно обеспечить одновременную работу с несколькими подключениями, при чём организацией очереди будет заниматься сам IIS.

Comment: hint: Собственно говоря не обязательно использовать IIS для масштабирования за счёт пула потоков. Класс ThreadPool лежит в неймспейсе System.Threading и доступен в любых проектах.
А проблема, я так понимаю, в том, что канал отправки используется один и тот же для всех активных подключений?

Comment: Alexey, да Вы правы один и тот же канал и мне кажется что задержка происходит именно из-за этого

Comment: Vyacheslav, а не лучше ли каждого нового подключения открывать новый канал? При условии конечно, что удалённый сервер допускает несколько входящих коннектов с одного хоста и протокол обмена данными подразумевает такой способ передачи данных. 
Других вариантов ускорить процесс нет. Разве что можно создавать отдельный поток и очередь сообщений на отправку для него. Поток будет отправлять сообщения из очереди крутясь в бесконечном цикле, отправку сделать без асинхронных вызовов. Процесс отправки станет чуть более прозрачным + экономия на накладных расходах создания тасков, но это миллисекунды...

Comment: @Vyacheslav: А почему не async/await? Он намного удобнее, чем BeginWrite/EndWrite.

Comment: VlaD, а в чем принципиальная разница в отношении производительности? Если её нет то тут, мне кажется, уже сугубо индивидуальный выбор)

Comment: Если вы в callback-методе вызываете EndWrite - то ничего не блокируется, потому что запись уже закончилась.

Comment: @PavelMayorov, это я понимаю, но проблема остается пакеты до конечного сервера доходят с задержкой. При 20-30 количестве активных подключений. НО если подключений 7,8. То пакеты хорошо доходят до конечного сервера

Comment: @Vyacheslav возможно, вам нужен просто более мощный сервер, раз вы по 2-3 секунды данные обрабатываете.

Comment: Это время из-за синхронной записи данных в БД. Поэтому может так набигать. Но к проблеме это не относится.